# relations in Google App Engine DataStore

Tags: java, web-services, google-app-engine

I'm thinking to use Google App Engine to host my Java WebService. But one question remains. Maybe you can help me to understand the datastore.

Imagine you got a relational database containing two tables. One is a list of organizations with an address. Second is your inventory. Let's say you are selling tablets. As long as they are in stock, they won't belong to any organization. But once sold, you want to link the tablet to an organization.

How would you map that to Google's DataStore? Using parent entities or not?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create entity relationship with JDO by modeling relationships between persistent objects using fields of the object types.

Check this link about [Entity Relationships in JDO](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships).

As the documentation says:

> You can model relationships between persistent objects using fields of
>   the object types. A relationship between persistent objects can be
>   described as owned, where one of the objects cannot exist without the
>   other, or unowned, where both objects can exist independently of their
>   relationship with one another. The App Engine implementation of the
>   JDO interface can model both owned and unowned one-to-one
>   relationships and one-to-many relationships, both unidirectional and
>   bidirectional.

*Hope it helps you.*

Comment: Yeah, I just read that I better use JPA or JDO to access the DataStore instead of the low-level API.

Comment: Don't use JDO or JPA. Even Google's guys don't recommend it. If you are not comfortable with the low-level API, use Objectify.